# Need help spotting the mistake in either jQuery or php in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm having trouble trying to figure out which part of my code is wrong, taking into account there are several languages involved.

Firstly I enqueue the script that I am going to run and then use `wp_localize_script` in the plugin main function file as follows:

```
// All scripts

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts' );

function theme_enqueue_scripts() {

  // Enqueue and Localize AJAX JavaScript Functions File 
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-categories-js', plugins_url( 'events-calendar-manager/inc/js/js.js' ), array('jquery'));
  wp_localize_script( 'ajax-categoreis-js', 'ajax_object_1', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin_ajax.php' ) ) );


}
```

The jQuery script looks like this:

```
// JavaScript Document

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        console.log('Started Jquery');

        var year='', month='', category='';

     $('#next_link').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();

         var $aid =$('#next_link');
         year =$aid.data('year');
         month =$aid.data('month');
         category =$aid.data('category');
         console.log('category: ' + category);

     });

    $('#previous_link').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();

         var $dai =$('#previous_link');
         year =$dai.data('year');
         month =$dai.data('month');
         category =$dai.data('category');
         console.log('category: ' + category);

     });

    console.log('category: ' + category);


    $.ajax({
         cache: false,
         timeout: 8000,
         type: 'POST',
         data: {action: 'get_post_filter_by_date_and_category', year : year, month: month, category: category},
         url: ajax_object_1.ajaxurl,
         success: function(data) {},
         error: function() {}
    });

});
```

**However** when I run it I get a mistake in the console saying : `Uncaught ReferenceError: ajax_object_1 is not defined` . This is weird as the object should be passed on using the wp_localize_script function.

What creates this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo here

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-categories-js' ...
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-categoreis-js', ...
```

See `ajax-categories-js !== ajax-categoreis-js`

```
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-categories-js', 'ajax_object_1', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin_ajax.php' ) ) );
```

Comment: Although now there are other jQuery mistakes :(

Answer (score 1):

Don't know nada about WP, but it looks like you have a typo here:

```
  wp_localize_script( 'ajax-categoreis-js', 'ajax_object_1', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin_ajax.php' ) ) );
```

You probably didn't mean to write `...'ajax-categoreis-js'...` but `...'ajax-categories-js'...`